# Detecting when another application is clipping the mouse cursor?

Tags: windows, winapi, setwindowshookex

What I am trying to do is to determine when another application is clipping the mouse cursor. I am using SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,...) to detect mouse movement. I could test the mouse position against its previous position every time my WH_MOUSE_LL callback is called, but this wont work if any of the sides of the application's window are touching the edge of the desktop as windows itself is also clipping the cursor.

More specifically, I am writing a program that overrides the default mapping of the virtual desktop when there are multiple monitors. I have everything working except in the case where a fullscreen application is running and constraining the mouse to its window. I cannot distinguish between the cursor actually trying to exit the side of the screen or if the current in-focus application is clipping it.

Is it possible to tell weather the in-focus app is clipping the mouse or maybe to prevent windows itself from constraining the cursor within the desktop, allowing the aforementioned check to work? Is there some other solution that I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I'm an idiot. `GetClipCursor(RECT*)` will do the trick.